# Variables In Sublime Text 3 Snippets

Tags: sublimetext3, variable-assignment, sublimetext, code-snippets

In PHPStorm, when creating a snippet, you can do something like this:

```
<!-- $VALUE$ Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="$NAME$" class="form-control">
</div>
```

With variables and such, so you can easily write a value. I'm wondering how to do the same thing with Sublime Text 3. This is what I have in my CDATA tag:

```
<!-- $VALUE Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="$NAME" class="form-control">
</div>
```

However, it's not working.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you want this ${1:defaultVar1} ${2:defaultVar2} . After inserting the snippet you can use tab to move and edit the next field (variable).

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the only variables that are available in snippets are [specified in the docs under snippets environment-variables](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html#environment-variables), as well as any you declare in a [`.tmPreferences`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/metadata.html) metadata file, or in a `.sublime-options` file. However, you can have [predefined values](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html) in snippets. For example, this snippet:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<!-- ${1:VALUE} Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="${2:NAME}" class="form-control">
</div>$0]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>form_group</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

gives this result when triggered:

[image]

You can then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the focus will move from field 1 to field 2:

[image]

and again to move to the exit point `$0`:

[image]

Comment: I think thtat's what the OP needs + 1.